# Actualización automática de un registro al llegar al valor 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Luego de agregar un trigger para actualizar la cantidad de un stock, es decir, restar determinada cantidad registrada en un ingreso. Tengo dudas y no he podido implementar otro para cuando el campo Stock llegue a cero, se agregue automáticamente en el campo Estado: "Agotado".

Dejo una captura del sistema y mas abajo el trigger que use para restar al stock los valores que se agregan a los ingresos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockExcedente AFTER INSERT ON detallerea
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE excedentes SET stock = stock - NEW.cantidad
        WHERE excedentes.idexcedente =NEW.idexcedente;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tabla `excedentes` deberías crear un trigger como sigue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updEstadoExcedente` BEFORE UPDATE ON `excedentes` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF NEW.stock <= 0 THEN
    SET NEW.Estado = 'Agotado';
    ELSE
    SET NEW.Estado = 'Disponible';
END IF;

END;
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que **en los triggers no se puede ejecutar un UPDATE sobre la misma tabla**, pero si se dispara el trigger **ANTES del UPDATE**, entonces estamos a tiempo de modificar los campos en `NEW` para que reflejen lo que necesitas.

Es importante también que la comparación sea no si *"es igual a cero"* sino si *"es menor o igual a cero"*, porque la actualización de stock podría haber dejado el stock en negativo (idealmente no debería pasar, si tu código lo contempla, pero no cuesta nada agregar un caracter en la comparación para asegurarnos de que no haya productos sin stock que figuren como *Disponibles*)